# Shared conda without sharing environments

Tags: conda

If conda is installed for all the users, e.g., in shared folder `/opt/miniconda3`, are environments shared as well?

For instance, if I `conda env create --file environment.yml`, will John be able to activate this environment as well? Or he needs to create it himself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the `.condarc` that each user loads. If everyone loads a `.condarc` that has a shared `envs_dirs` defined, then the envs will be shared. Otherwise, everyone will need to create their own. Just be aware that sharing writable envs is rather precarious. For example, a careless user imprudently installing new packages in a shared env can end up invalidating other users' code.

A shared `pkgs_dirs` on the other hand can be a great way to reduce disk usage across users while still allowing their envs to be independent (i.e., everyone has their own `envs_dirs`).